# select parent and parent's child from the same table and order asc

Tags: mysql, sql

i have try to select all parent and all parent's child and then join count(*) of every parent's children to the parent's row.

```
SELECT a.*,COUNT(b.*) FROM cat AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cat AS b WHERE b.ana_cat=a.id)
ON b.ana_cat=a.id
WHERE a.ana_cat=0
```

but does'nt work, since i have no much knowledge in sql.
How can i do this to get result like this:

```
|id|cat_title|ana_cat|COUNT(*)|
-------------------------------
|1 |Cultures |   0   |   4    |
|4 |Haoussa  |   1   |   0    |
|9 |Zarma    |   1   |   0    |
|7 |Peuls    |   1   |   0    |
|8 |Toubou   |   1   |   0    |
|3 |Histoire |   0   |   2    |
|6 |Nigerien |   3   |   0    |
|2 |Africain |   3   |   0    |
|1 |Divers   |   0   |   0    |
|1 |Archive  |   0   |   0    |
```

Comment: my code not work, i am sure that it contain error

Comment: Your results show rows where `ana_cat` is not `0`.  Yet your sample code filters on that condition.  Confusing.

Comment: me too i am confusing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way to get rows as you want.

```
SELECT c.title,ca.title,concat(c.id,'-',ca.id) as sort_column FROM
```

cat c
join cat as ca on ca.ana_cat = c.id order by sort_column

Comment: give me this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*),id
    FROM cat ca
    WHERE ca.ana_cat = c.id
   )
FROM ca' at line 2`

Comment: thank you very much. yes it work. is it possible to get parent on top then under each parent get all child ?

Comment: You can do it on your view page easily. First store the parent category title in a variable making it heading in merged cells. Then in every row check for that variable if it changes then make it heading and update the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think a correlated subquery is more suited to your problem:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM cat ca
        WHERE ca.ana_cat = c.id
       )
FROM cat c 
WHERE c.ana_cat = 0;
```

I'm not sure if the `WHERE` is needed or not.

Comment: thank you. but i want to get child after parent's row directly even if their id is so big. is it possible?

Comment: @housseinahmed . . . That is not the question that you asked here.  This answers the question you have asked here.

Comment: i have try to select all parent **and all parent's child** and then join count(*) of every parent's children to the parent's row.